# How can I adjust the section and row in UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I get the correct location when I'm clicking on the location cell?

Because in my main story Board there are two rows, 1st one is location and the 2nd one is date picker cell.

[image]

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {

        if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 2
        {
            let authStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

            if authStatus == .NotDetermined
            {
                locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                return
            }

            if updatingLocation
            {
                stopLocationManager()

            } else
            {
                location = nil
                lastLocationError = nil
                placemark = nil
                lastGeocodingError = nil
                startLocationManager()
            }
            updateLabels()
            configureGetButton()

        }


        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        textField.resignFirstResponder()


        if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 1 { if !datePickerVisible {
            showDatePicker()
        }
        else
        {
            hideDatePicker()
            }
        }}
```

Comment: please specify what you exactly want to know, your question title and the description seems to be different..

Comment: i just want a if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 2
        {...}if this is correct then why i will not get the answer after click on location cell

Comment: Ok , Thats fine So the above code doesn't work for you? right

Comment: please put breakpoints on both the conditions and find where the control goes ,what about the other one is date picker works fine?

Comment: if will put the index path.section == 2 && index path.row == 1 then it will shows both action address and date also... but when i put index path.row 2 or 0 then it will not shows the address

Comment: I am not sure please try somthing like this   if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 1{date picker stuffs}  else if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 2 {location stuffs} then tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 0-based indexes, so first row is 0, second - 1. You should ask for row == 0.